# getting Context from Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an Activity `StaggeredPrenotaTour` starting a second Activity `Details` through an `Intent`, the class `Details` contains an `AsyncTask` class `ReservationTask`, and after some operations to the network, it has to pass a Java `Object` back go the `StaggeredPrenotaTour` class.

`StaggeredPrenotaTour` at the point where it starts `Details`:

```
      Intent message = new Intent(staggeredPrenotaTour, Details.class);
      message.putExtras(bundle);
      getContext().startActivity(message);
```

Basically I need pass my `Object` to the current context of `StaggeredPrenotaTour`, so that I don't have to create a new instance of it but update the contents of the current one!

Unfortunately I've read that there is no way you can get a `Context` from an `Intent`, so how is another way to get the working instance of `StaggeredPrenotaTour` inside `Details` class?

Comment: Try to use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so how is another way to get the working instance of StaggeredPrenotaTour inside Details class?

You don't.

> so that I don't have to create a new instance of it but update the contents of the current one!

It sounds like these two activities should share a common data model, perhaps implemented via a singleton manager. `StaggeredPrenotaTour` can use the revised data in its `onResume()` method, which will be called as part of it coming back into the foreground after `Details` is destroyed (e.g., user presses BACK).

Or, use an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, etc.). Have `ReservationTask` raise a `ReservationResultsEvent` that `StaggeredPrenotaTour` subscribes to, so `StaggeredPrenotaTour` can find out the results of the work.

Comment: @CrisBenois: You can read about `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, and the rest of the activity lifecycle callbacks in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks).

Answer (score 1):

> Starting another activity doesn't have to be one-way. You can also
>   start another activity and receive a result back. To receive a result,
>   call startActivityForResult() (instead of startActivity()).

For details, read the guide on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)